# Como separar os dados de um requisição GET e inserir no banco mysql com php

Tags: php, mysql, get

Tenho uma formulário de perguntas com várias perguntas, após a pessoa responder tem um botão salvar que envia as respostas e perguntas para o `salva.php`

> Segue o get (url):

```
salva.php?
data_cadastro=2017-07-08 
& cli_id = 1
& cli_nome=OTACIO+BARBOSA
& cli_end=RUA+A
& cli_tel=3333333333
& cli_data_nasc=1900-01-01
& cli_cidade=TESTE
& cli_estado=MG
& usu_id = 1
& 1=3
& 2=0
& 3=1
& 4=5
& 5=3
& 6=1
& 7=0
& 8=3
& 9=0
& 10=1
& 11=5
& 12=5
& 13=5
& 14=3
& 15=3
& 16=0
& 17=0
& 18=1
& 19=1
& 20=0
& 21=0
& 22=1
& 23=3
& 24=5
```

Eu preciso salvar esses dados na tabela respostas:

```
resp_fixa_id
resp_fixa_id_perg
resp_fixa_id_cliente
resp_fixa_id_resp
resp_fixa_data_cad
```

Sendo da seguinte forma:

```
resp_fixa_id          = data_cadastro
resp_fixa_id_perg     = ( é o sequencial mmostrado de 1 a 24 )
resp_fixa_id_cliente  = cli_id
resp_fixa_id_resp     = é o que vem na frente do sequencial (1 = 3 (no caso seria o 3))
resp_fixa_data_cad    =  data_cadastro
```

Ou seja preciso deixa-lo da seguinte forma para inserir no banco:

```
INSERT INTO resposta (resp_fixa_id,resp_fixa_id_perg,resp_fixa_id_cliente,resp_fixa_id_resp,resp_fixa_data_cad) 
                        VALUES('NULL','1','1','3','2017-07-08');
INSERT INTO resposta (resp_fixa_id,resp_fixa_id_perg,resp_fixa_id_cliente,resp_fixa_id_resp,resp_fixa_data_cad) 
                        VALUES('NULL','2','1','0','2017-07-08');
INSERT INTO resposta (resp_fixa_id,resp_fixa_id_perg,resp_fixa_id_cliente,resp_fixa_id_resp,resp_fixa_data_cad) 
                        VALUES('NULL','2','1','1','2017-07-08');
```

Como poderia fazer essa conversão ?

Obs: Esse sequencial é o numero de perguntas na tela que a pessoa respondeu, mais não é fico, pode ser mais ou mesmo essa quantidade.

Complemento:

```
$total_de_perguntas = count($_POST)-9;

$VarLoja            = $_POST['loja'];
$VarDataCadastro    = $_POST['data_cadastro'];
$VarUsuario         = $_POST['usuario'];
$VarNome            = $_POST['cli_nome'];
$VarEndereco        = $_POST['cli_end'];
$VarTelefone        = $_POST['cli_tel'];
$VarDataNascimento  = $_POST['cli_data_nasc'];
$VarCidade          = $_POST['cli_cidade'];
$VarEstado          = $_POST['cli_estado'];

$iniciaPerguntas = 1; 

while($iniciaPerguntas <= $total_de_perguntas) {


    $VarRespostas =  $_POST["$iniciaPerguntas"];

    $VarString = '$Query'.$iniciaPerguntas = "INSERT INTO sug_respostas (resp_fixa_id,
    resp_fixa_id_perg,
    resp_fixa_id_cliente,
    resp_fixa_id_usu,
    resp_fixa_id_resp,
    resp_fixa_data)
    VALUES (NULL,
    '$iniciaPerguntas',
    '$VarNewNumClientes',
    '$VarUsuario',
    '$VarRespostas',
    '$VarDataCadastro');"; 



    $Result = '$Result'.$iniciaPerguntas = $conn->query($VarString);

    $iniciaPerguntas++; 

}
```

> Notice: Undefined index: in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sistemas\cadastro_geral\sugestoes\salva.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sistemas\cadastro_geral\sugestoes\salva.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sistemas\cadastro_geral\sugestoes\salva.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sistemas\cadastro_geral\sugestoes\salva.php on line 28

Comment: Não seria melhor enviar as perguntas e respostas numa só variável a tratar isso como Array no PHP? Por exemplo: `salva.php?...&respostas=1,3,2,0,3,1` onde as posições ímpares são o id da pergunda e as pares a resposta da pergunta do id à esquerda. Após receber as informações, você pode percorrer essa array e gravar cada pergunta e sua respectiva resposta no banco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conta o número total de variáveis enviadas no $_POST e diminui pelo número de variáveis que são fixas. Com esse resultado, você saberá quantas perguntas foram feitas.

No seu caso, você possui 9 variáveis fixas e 33 no total. Basta fazer a conta abaixo:

```
$total_de_perguntas = count($_POST)-9;
```

Comment: @OtácioBarbosa Tente alterar o `$iniciaPerguntas = 1;` para `$iniciaPerguntas = 9;` porque só deve dar 24 loops no script, que é a diferença entre o total geral dos posts fixos e as variáveis.

Comment: , Deu certo, mais na verdade era uma bagunça de variáveis que eu tinha feito, inseriu ok, Obrigado, pela ajuda.

Answer (score 5):

Para essa quantidade de informações, não é aconselhável utilizar o método GET por causa do limite de 1024 caracteres e também é boa pratica utilizar esse método quando for buscar algo. O melhor seria utilizar o método POST, isso você muda no formulário dentro do HTML, através do atributo method da tag FORM.

O conteúdo do arquivo **salvar.php** ficaria assim:

```
// CODIGO PHP RETORNA AS INFORMAÇÕES DO POST
$client_id = $_POST['cli_id'];
$cli_nome = $_POST['cli_nome'];
```

....(assim por diante os restante das informações)

Segue o link explicando mais como capturar essas informações:
https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.external.php

Depois de capturar as informações, você precisar guardar no banco de dados, com PHP segue um link com exemplo de como abrir uma conexão com o banco de dados e fazer o insert:
http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/php-programming/curso-de-php-inserindo-dados-em-um-banco-de-dados-mysql/

Obs.: Espero ter ajudado com essas informações, não entendi bem o nível de conhecimento que você tem de PHP e então procurei deixar tudo bem estruturado com link para consulta.

Comment: Então essa parte de passar para post e como pegar da outra parte e tranquilo, a dúvida maior e o seguinte que as perguntas ali pode ser as 24 que tá ali ou 20 ou 25 ou 30 ... e como pegar essa variação que tá me pegando

Comment: Entendi, você pode verifica se a variável existe no POST, tipo assim quer saber se tem até 24, ai verifica se existe a variável 24 no POST. Da seguinte forma: if(isset($_POST['24']){ //EXISTE}else{ // NÃO EXISTE} a função isset verifica se a variável existe. Se a variavél sempre existir, você pode verifica se existe conteudo nela tipo if($_POST['24'] == ''){//TEM VALOR}else{//NAO TEM VALOR}

Comment: Ok, vou testar,  Obrigado

Comment: @OtácioBarbosa `$_POST` é uma array, você pode fazer um loop em tudo que houver nela com `foreach($_POST as $chave=>$valor) { /* ... */ }`.